# Django inline formset with model subclasses (or just multiple models)

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I want to display a form to answer multiple types of questions in a survey/test (kind of like Google Forms). My models are set up such that I have a `Test` model, an `Answer` model with a foreign key to the `Test`, and subclasses of `Answer` (such as multiple choice, short answer) with the necessary extra fields for that question type.

My first thought was to use an inline formset for to display the fields for the answers. However, if I create an inline formset for `Answer`, the form only shows the fields for this superclass, not for the specific subclass answer types. And it doesn't appear (based on my searches) that it's possible to create an inline formset with multiple model types. Is this functionality possible?

(It occurs to me that it might be possible by essentially manually rolling a formset by creating a list of individual forms for every `Answer`, but this doesn't seem like a very elegant solution.)

Comment: If you are using CBV's check django-extra-views includes inline formsets (Create and Update View).

Comment: The issue isn't the lack of a CBV for inline formsets; it's that inline formsets aren't getting the job done.

Comment: I sorry but I don't see any kind of code (model related) in order to be more clear, if I am right you have an Abstract Answer model class and from there you implement a concrete? if yes then again a ModelForm for each answer and inlines could be the solution, in order to avoid DRY I would check the extra views classes and override them to inject the different models.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correct: you can create dynamic inline for each model:

```
def get_inline_by_model(m):
    return type(
        'YourInline', 
        (admin.StackedInline, ), 
        {'model' : m, 'extra' : 0,'form' : YourAdminForm,'max_num' : 1,'fields' :('key','value')} 
    )
```

and in your admin model:

```
inlines = [
        get_inline_by_model(models.YourModel),
    ]
```

and in this way you can use the same inline form for multiple models

Comment: What I'm trying to create isn't in the admin. It's just in a normal view.